# Why only few flutter plugins require WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) requires WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() but not [xmpp_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/xmpp_plugin), [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences/example) or [device_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus) ? As per my knowledge plugins require platform specific channels due to which WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() is placed in main() function of flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

Most plugins should not require `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized` because the `WidgetsFlutterBinding` instance normally is initialized automatically.  Some plugins require that it be explicitly called because they need the instance to be initialized earlier.

From the [`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html):

> You only need to call this method if you need the binding to be initialized before calling `runApp`
> .